# Шаблоны в WPF | Не работает кнопка

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Сделал шаблон для кнопки, но почему-то после этого кнопка перестала быть кликабельной. Почему так?
Вот сам XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LimeGreen"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightBlue"></GradientStop>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"></ContentPresenter>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="300" Height="160" Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">ggg</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Как вы это определили? При нажатие нету "вдавливания"? Ну наверно потому, что вы написали только часть стиля, в котором вы не обработали это.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так может подскажете как и это обработать?)

Comment: Сделайте кнопку без стилей и чего либо еще, просто `<Button/>`, далее в дизайнере нажмите на нее правой кнопкой мыши "Изменить стиль" - ["Правка копии"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC876.png), выбирайте имя и куда его добавлять. У вас сгенерируется код стандартной кнопки, по которому и смотрите, что есть в кнопке такого, чего не сделали вы (дам подсказку, триггеры) .